# Terminating ssh remote command execution on SIGPIPE

Tags: ssh, remote-access

```
ssh remotehost "remote_command" | more
```

This executes `remote_command` on `remotehost`, and paginates the output of `remote_command`. If the user is unwilling to scroll through all the pages, he might press `q` at the `--MORE--` prompt. Unfortunately this doesn't stop the ssh process (and the remote command). The user have to press `^C` to actually terminate the processes. When user presses `q` more terminates and ssh gets SIGPIPE but continues as `remote_command` didn't finish executing. Is there any way I can terminate ssh and remote execution when the user quits the pager? I don't want the user to press ^C as he wouldn't be required to do so if a local file was being catted (in fact he wouldn't know this command is being executed over a ssh tunnel remotely).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change the command to call more on the remote server? Also you will have to force a pty as wfaulk mentioned.  Assuming it is another unix system this should be fine. i.e.

ssh -t name@system "command | more"

Fyi. less is more :)

Comment: Forcing a terminal is messing up with newlines etc. And again, pagination on remote side is not good as I am on a terminal (router CLI shell) which has configurable number of lines per page - and that can't be communicated to pager on remote side.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but try getting a pty from the remote machine by passing the '`-t`' flag to `ssh`.